# What is the recommended default hadoop-metrics2.properties content for Hadoop 1.0.3?

Tags: hadoop, jmx

I've been searching for a default hadoop-metrics2.properties file which simply exposes all available metrics via JMX, but couldn't find one.

The currently file the comes shipped with 1.0.3 is quite empty and refers to the package information, which doesn't reveal the names of the metric classes.

Answer (score 0):

To enable JMX for remote monitoring, you do not need to modify your hadoop-metrics2.properties file. Instead, you would have to add something similar to the following to your start script: `HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8004"` (that example could go in your `hadoop-env.sh` file).

In addition to exposing the JMX metrics, you should note that all of your JMX metrics are available via HTTP (for namenode in this example) at: http://namenode-host:50070/jmx

If you wish to view your Hadoop metrics over a local JMX connection, no additional configuration changes are necessary. Simply run `jconsole` on your local instance.

Answer (score -1):

(Add the following to your metrics2.properties for metrics dump in every 10 secs and the file will be in the $HADOOP_HOME/logs dir)

```
*.sink.file.class=org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.FileSink
*.period=10


namenode.sink.file.filename=./logs/namenode-metrics.out
datanode.sink.file.filename=./logs/datanode-metrics.out
jobtracker.sink.file.filename=./logs/jobtracker-metrics.out
tasktracker.sink.file.filename=./logs/tasktracker-metrics.out
```

Comment: Does this expose the metrics as jmx?

Comment: This actually dumps out the metrics that are actually available over jmx into file so that other programs (lik Splunk) can read the metrics with out having to use JMX apis.